# Palavra para contrato que está a sofrer rescisão

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, neologismos, composições

Busco uma palavra que defina um ente legal (contrato) que esteja a sofrer um processo de rescisão.

Meu processo de raciocínio até agora:

- Ao ente legal que rescinde chama-se **rescisória**.
- Ao ente legal que sofreu rescisão (concluída) chama-se **rescindido**.
- O ato de causar rescisão a um ente legal (verbo) **rescindir**.

Enquanto a ação rescisória está em curso, o ente legal alvo da rescisória encontra-se *válido*, logo não está (ainda) *rescindido*.

Traçando um paralelo com o verbo **educar** temos:

- O que educa: *educador*
- O que recebeu educação *educado*
- O que *está a receber educação*: **educando**

Logo o que busco seria correspondente à palavra **educando** mas para o verbo rescindir.

Existe palavra para definir este estado como descrito acima?

Comment: Eu diria *contrato em (processo de) rescisão*. Existe a palavra [*rescindendo*](https://lfg.jusbrasil.com.br/noticias/372006/que-se-entende-por-juizo-rescindendo-e-juizo-rescisorio-gabriela-gomes-coelho-ferreira), mas é também 'ente que rescinde', mas com uma diferença técnica de *rescisório*. Mas eu não sou legista; talvez haja aqui alguém que saiba melhor.

Comment: @Jacinto meu instinto me diz que seria **"rescindo"**, mas como não consigo isolar a regra de formação destes substantivos, não me atrevo a usá-lo.

Comment: *Rescindo* não me cheira. Googlei *contrato rescindo, contrato está rescindo, contrato foi rescindo*; encontram-se resultados, mas parecem ser enganos, que queriam dizer *rescindido*. Existem poucas palavras paralelas a *educando* ('que está a ser objeto de...'); só me lembro de *instruendo* e *formando*; coincidem com o gerúndio ou andam lá perto.

Comment: @Jacinto eu pesquisei também antes de criar a questão acima. Como não existe tal palavra, nem me atrevi a colocá-la no corpo da questão.

Comment: "NA FORMA DE CONTRATAÇÃO DO ESTÁGIO. ACÓRDÃO **RESCINDENDO** QUE, EMBORA ADMITA A IMPOSSIBILIDADE DE RECONHECIMENTO DO VÍNCULO EMPREGATÍCIO SEM O REQUISITO DO CONCURSO PÚBLICO, DETERMINA O PAGAMENTO"

Comment: @AndréLyra te importas em colocar teu comentário como uma resposta, para que possa ser votada?

Answer (score 1):

O que você procura é um **adjetivo gerundivo**, ou seja: um adjetivo derivado da forma gerundiva de um verbo latino.

Exemplo de adjetivo gerundivo: [vincendo](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vincendo). Esse adjetivo deriva do verbo latino gerundivo *vincéndus* (forma gerundiva do verbo latino *vinco*) por intermédio do verbo português *vencer*.

Do mesmo modo, é por intermédio do verbo português *rescindir* que do verbo latino gerundivo *rescindéndus* (forma gerundiva do verbo latino *rescindo*) deriva o adjetivo gerundivo *rescindendo*.

Em síntese:

- vinco => vincéndus => vencer => vincendo (ou vincend**a**, no feminino)
- rescindo => rescindéndus => rescindir => rescindendo (ou rescindend**a**, no feminino)

Um exemplo de uso do adjetivo gerundivo **rescindendo** consta no parágrafo único do [art. 971 do CPC brasileiro](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2015/lei/l13105.htm#art971) (lei federal 13.105/15):

> *A escolha de relator recairá, sempre que possível, em juiz que não haja participado do julgamento **rescindendo***

Outro exemplo de uso consta no verbete `Ação rescisória` do [Glossário Jurídico do Supremo Tribunal Federal](http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/glossario/) brasileiro:

> *O prazo prescricional dessa ação é de dois anos, a partir do trânsito em julgado da sentença **rescindenda***